# Cleanup of the "version" tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Currently there are a multitude of tags for questions about alternative movie versions. First of all, the tags [versions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/versions) and [alternate-version](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternate-version), which have largely the same tag descriptions and usages (some questions even use both tags). Then there are the less frequently used [movie-edition](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie-edition) and [directors-cut](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directors-cut) (which is more specialized, but could easily be covered by a broader tag).

**Since the current situation is overly confusing, how to proceed with those tags?**

**EDIT:** Since the appraoch proposed in *NapoleonWilson*'s answer has been unanimously accepted by the community, I'd hereby ask the moderators to make [directors-cut](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directors-cut), [versions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/versions) and [movie-edition](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie-edition) synonyms of [alternate-version](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternate-version) and tag this question as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) when done.

Comment: The moderators will do this shortly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [versions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/versions), [alternate-version](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternate-version) and [movie-edition](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie-edition) seem to cover the same topics, I'd propose to merge them into a single tag. Though I'm yet unsure what to call that tag. [versions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/versions) seems a bit too generic (yet, it's Movies & TV, so what else could it mean than a movie or TV show version?), so maybe [alternate-version](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternate-version) might be a better choice. Likewise I'm not sure if to make the other two synonyms of the new tag or delete them completely. The latter would be cleaner but would result in mass edits (though, there aren't too many questions yet anyway).

Then the question remains what to do with [directors-cut](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directors-cut). It covers a more specific case of alternate version. But then again it's covered equally well by the broader tag and it being too specific isn't a good idea either, since this opens the question if there should also be tags for "Special Editions", "Remastered Versions" or "Special Fan-Approved De-Remastered Non-Director's Cuts". I would thus propose [directors-cut](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directors-cut) to be a synonym of the new single version tag (here a synonym is more appropriate than deleting, since Director's Cut is a common term likely to come up again as a tag).

Comment: Time's up, decision one-sided, doing as proposed in this answer.

Comment: I thought this consolidation was unnecessary. Different editions of the same movie are not the same thing as alternate versions".

Comment: @TylerDurden What would be the difference between *"alternate editions"* and *"alternate versions"*? Can you give a distinguishing definition warranting and facilitating an easy tag separation? (By the way, if you thought this, you didn't voice your concerns, if you still think this, I'm afraid it's too late, or you might want to write a new answer on this question or open a new meta discussion.)